# Scala - why an empty argument list is declared before implicit list

Tags: scala, implicit

Some places (e.g. Play `Form.bindFromRequest`) use an empty parameter list before the implicit parameter list. Why?
IMHO, it has the disadvantage of requiring extra parentheses when the parameter is explicitly passed as in `form.bindFromRequest()(request)`.
Not sure what is the advantage then?

Comment: You're not allowed to write it without one, no? IMO that would lead to very confusing behaviour thanks to the uniform access principle - what looked like a simple property access could be doing arbitrarily complex things with implicits.

Comment: @lmm You can write this same method without the empty parameter list (or so says a cursory attempt in the REPL). Class constructors are given an empty parameter list automatically if only implicits are defined, but methods seem to work okay without them. Whether it's a good idea to do this, I don't know.

Comment: Also note that though the method is defined with an empty argument list before the implicit arguments, you can still invoke it like `form.bindFromRequest` without any warnings from the compiler. So most probably it's better to follow the convention when defining the function but when invoking you can omit the brackets (if the method has no side effect, because according to the style guides it's better to keep the brackets to make it clear that a side effect is happening by calling this function).

Answer (score 1):

A `def` with a parameter list has a different type than one with no parameter list. This doesn't matter under direct invocation, but if you pass that method as an argument to another method, it does.

In example, if you define your method like so:

```
def func1 = { println("Hello"); 1 }
```

You can't pass it to this method:

```
def consume(f: () => Double) = // ...
```

as it's type is simply Double, albeit a very lazy one. On the other hand this function will work fine:

```
def func2() = { println("Hello"); 2 }
```

I'm not saying this is the explicit reason why they did it, but if they had an actual reason, it will almost certainly be tied to type.

EDIT:

The difference between them in practical terms it mostly comes down to where they can be used.

The call-by-value item can only be used in a parameter list to a function/method (afaik). Since it can only be passed in a parameter list, you can't store it in a variable and use it in multiple locations (without changing it to an explicit instance of `T`).

And as you can see here, they aren't interchangeable per se:

```
scala> def f(s: => String) { println(s) }
f: (s: => String)Unit

scala> def s1 = () => { "Hello" }
s1: () => String

scala> f(s1)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : () => String
 required: String
              f(s1)
                ^
```

So imagine I wanted to store an array of callbacks that users pass to me.. I can't use `=> T` here:

```
scala> val a: Array[=> Int] = Array()
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but '=>' found.
       val a: Array[=> Int] = Array()
                    ^

scala> val a: Array[() => Int] = Array()
a: Array[() => Int] = Array()
```

So if I want to store such items, and pass them around internally, using `=> T` (and keeping it lazily evaluated) is not an option.

I think it's best to not think of the `=>` in `=> T` and `() => T` as meaning the same thing. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: True, but you can define consume as 
`def consume(f: => Double)`
which is equivalent to your consume, is it?

Comment: That is a pass by name parameter not a function1.

Comment: Sorry, I mean Function0.

Comment: This is exactly what I don't understand: what is the practical difference between the types `=> T` and `() => T` and why Scala distinguishes between them.

Comment: I updated my answer to try to clarify the difference a little.

Comment: You can call `consume(func1 _)`. It's a bit less pretty than `consume(func2)` but it still works.